# Exception with OAuth2.0 service call

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I write some code in Microsoft Visual Studio .NET with C#. I want to call one rest service using RestSharp 106.3.1 library that i get from Microsoft NuGet.
this is a banking service that has no argument and list all customer debit card.
I get bearer access token from another service and I can call getCards service with System.Net.Http.HttpClient successfully. but I want to use RestSharp.

my code is:

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(webSrvUri);
client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(accessToken, "Bearer");
var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.Resource = "getCards";
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
RestSharp.IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

but this code generate following content as result:

> {"timestamp":"2018-07-03 10:16:49","status":500,"error":"Internal
>   Server
>   Error","exception":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException","message":"No
>   content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: ; line: 1, column:
>   0]","path":"/core/getCards"}

what do I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have added the header as JSON? whether you have added the requested body in JSON format?

Comment: This service does not have a body. However, adding the type of Json to the body again produces the same error.